Catch UserID or SetExternalID on OneSignal in Dart Flutter
This code initialize and create in onesignal but no return function for catch player ID or set External ID any forms
    import 'dart:async';
    import 'package:onesignal_flutter/onesignal_flutter.dart';

   Future onesignal(String? externalId) async {

     OneSignal.Debug.setLogLevel(OSLogLevel.verbose);

     OneSignal.initialize("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

     OneSignal.Notifications.requestPermission(true);

     await OneSignal.setExternalUserId(externalId);

     OSDeviceState? deviceState = await OneSignal.getDeviceState();
     String? playerId = deviceState?.userId;

     if (playerId != null) {
      FFAppState().fftoken = playerId;
     }

    }

return PlayerId or send External User ID

Welcome to stackoverflow. It might be helpful to include what version of onesignal_flutter you are using. Are you asking how to return playerId from this function?

Oh sorry > onesignal_flutter: ^5.0.4

Hi again. What exactly is your question? Could you edit your post and clarify that?

Yes, exactly, this function not return player ID and i have no idea why.

To return the variable playerId you would have to change the signature of your function to Future<String?> onesignal(String? externalId) and inside your function add a return statement: return playerId; .
